# Perl Scrappy select using class attribute

Tags: perl, web-scraping

I was trying to scrape using Perl [`Scrappy`](http://metacpan.org/module/Scrappy). I would like to select html elements with class attribute using 'select'.

```html
<p>
  <h1>
   <a href='http://test.com'>Test</a>
   <a href='http://list.com'>List</a>
  </h1>
</p>
<p class='parent-1'>
  <h1>
   <a class='child-1' href="http://sample.com">SampleLink</a>
   <a class='child-2' href="http://list.com">List</a>
  </h1>
</p>
```

I need to get element('a' tag) with class name 'child-1' which is a child nod of `<p class='parent-1'>` using select method.

I have tried like this

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Scrappy;

my  $scraper = Scrappy->new;
$scraper->get($url);
$scraper->select('p a')->data;
```

But it will select the first 'p' tag also.

Could you please help me with this?

Comment: Have you even tried anything?

Comment: yes, i did tried with 'select',  $scraper->select('p a')->data; but it will select the first <p> also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bearing in mind [choroba's warning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33283323/622310), to select an `<a>` element with a class of `child-1` that is a child of a `<p>` element with a class of `parent-1` you would write

```
$scraper->select('p.parent-1 > a.child-1')
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in HTML, a `<p>` tag can't contain a `<h1>` tag. In fact, the HTML is parsed as

```xml
<p></p>
  <h1>
   <a href='http://test.com'>Test</a>
   <a href='http://list.com'>List</a>
  </h1>    
<p class='parent-1'></p>
  <h1>
   <a class='child-1' href="http://sample.com">SampleLink</a>
   <a class='child-2' href="http://list.com">List</a>
  </h1>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I removed the h1 tag from html. And it still i could not able to select the element using tag and class name. Could you please let me know how to select an element using class name

Comment: @user2190981: See [Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors).